# OS X Yosemite fonts jagged/blurry on external monitor

Tags: fonts, external-display, osx-yosemite

Anyone have any suggestions on possible fixes for jagged text on my external monitor hooked up to my rMBP? I am using an ASUS MX279H monitor. The text is pretty jagged everywhere. Safari, Messages, etc.

Windows (good):

[image]

OS X (bad):

[image]

I have googled extensively and I have already tried:

1. Turning on/off LCD font smoothing in system prefs
2. The defaults write applefontsmoothing terminal command
3. [The infamous Ruby script](http://www.ireckon.net/2013/03/force-rgb-mode-in-mac-os-x-to-fix-the-picture-quality-of-an-external-monitor/) floating around that supposedly fixes a similar issue for some
4. Changing my monitor to use rgb
5. Resetting monitor
6. Calibrating monitor in OS X
7. Using Mini DisplayPort to VGA adapter instead of my normal Mini DisplayPort to HDMI

After reading some forums, it seems like people have been complaining more about this issue with Yosemite due to a system font change. Any ideas anyone? When my Windows machine is hooked up to the same monitor the text looks fine.

Comment: It's hard to tell what your screen looks like on my screen ;) but both of those look OK-ish to me, for that resolution. Bear in mind that monitor has a very poor resolution for its size [27" 1080p], so everything's going to look fuzzy.

Comment: @Tetsujin I realize that, but OS X is _much_ worse than when I have a Windows machine hooked up to the monitor. So it is certainly an OS X issue.

Comment: Did you ever fix this? Then please answer your own question for future readers?

Comment: did you fix it? I have the same problem :(

Comment: No, never fixed.

Comment: I like Apple. We got two Apple computers in our household, but one thing Apple seem to have serious problems with, its font rendering on external screens. I got two amazing screens, that look great on linux and windows. Messing with the font smoothing makes minimal difference. I found my peace with it and decided MacOS just isn't fit for purpose for multi monitor setups. It kinda works, but really not very nice looking.